# Count the changes in an array

Tags: code-golf, array

Your task today is to write a program or function that takes an array of integers, and counts the number of times, reading it left to right, that the value changes. This is easier to show with an example: `[1 1 1 2 2 5 5 5 5 17 3] => [1 1 1 **2** 2 **5** 5 5 5 **17** **3**] => 4`

Test case:

```
Input           |   Output
[]              |   0
[0]             |   0
[0 1]           |   1
[0 0]           |   0
[1 2 3 17]      |   3
[1 1 1 2 2 3]   |   2
[-3 3 3 -3 0]   |   3
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), fewest bytes wins!

Comment: Is my answer valid if the result is always correctly calculated, but if it's 0, `False` is printed instead?

Comment: @FlipTack That depends on the language. In general, if I can say `2+False` and it errors, that's not fine, but if I get `2`, that's fine.

Comment: @FlipTack By default, [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9067/68615) is the consensus.

Comment: Is empty output for `0` acceptable?

Comment: @Titus yes it is.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 2 bytes

```
dz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P6Xq//9oQwUQNAJCUyg0NFcwjgUA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D@l6r9LyP/oWK5oAxBWMASTILahgpGCsYIJmAWCRiA@kKdrrACCQMogFgA).

#### Explanation

```
     % Implicit input
d    % Consecutive differences
z    % Number of nonzeros
     % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 38 bytes

```python
f=lambda x=0,*y:y>()and(x!=y[0])+f(*y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU1LCsMgFNz3FK8LiaZP0CSLEjAXEReWIA20JtgU4umtL2VgvovZ8v5cY19KMC//fsweDqOwzWOeuPBx5sfVZKucuAXeZlHCmsCn5DMsEaxDqBsR6r/UZDV22ONAhUZCRwVF2SOhinLjBWBLS9x5w6S@f0BOwL4NMODnAUJ9PJ0QovwA)

Comment: Huh, did know know you could use a default arg like that, nice find.

Comment: [Easier test case format](https://tio.run/##VU/LCoMwELz7FdtDMGsj@OhJiD8iImmNraBRYgrm69NED20Z2J2ZZXfY1ZrXokrnBj6J@d4L2HnGElvZmqJQPd0v3DZZi9eBJhadkZvpHmKTG3BoWgZ@FgrLz3aonBWsZLeTBhTBCDItWYBvWRvNYu8mqZ7m5W95Qb2gWq6ajkbOiDAsGgKFUcE3GKPgC62F/R9UEcCqR2VoTEhKeg1pDYS8YyDwk0WAHssM/EsHQ0T3AQ)

Comment: @Dennis How does the function exit the recursive loop when the array is empty? I don't see how this doesn't end in a `maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

Comment: @Ioannes Once there's only one element (**x**) left, `y>()` will evaluate to *False*, so the code following `and` doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 33 bytes

```hs
f(a:b:r)=sum[1|a/=b]+f(b:r)
f _=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00j0SrJqkjTtrg0N9qwJlHfNilWO00DJMSVphBva/A/NzEzT8FWoaAoM69EQUUhTSHaUAcEjYHQCEib6JjE/gcA)

---

**Bonus:** Somewhat curious point-free arithmetic version (44 bytes)

```hs
sum.(tail>>=zipWith((((0^).(0^).abs).).(-)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzv7g0V0@jJDEzx87OtiqzIDyzJEMDCAziNPXARGJSsaYekK2rqan5PzcxM0/BVqGgKDOvREFFIU0h2lAHBI2B0AhIm@iYxP7/l5yWk5he/F83uaAAAA)

Given an input `[1,1,4,3,3,3]`, we first take the difference of adjacent entries (`[0,3,-1,0,0]`), then the `abs`olute value: `[0,3,1,0,0]`. Taking zero to the power of each element the first time yields `[1,0,0,1,1]`, and a second time inverts the list: `[0,1,1,0,0]` (`(1-)` would also work here instead of `(0^)`). Finally we take the `sum` of the list to get `2`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 42 bytes

```python
lambda a:sum(x!=y for x,y in zip(a,a[1:]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HUnLCoUgEN33FdNOYYK0VkJfYi4mLnKFMukB2c9bE4fzTvn4r1EXP4xlpmX6EZDZz0Vc9ZDBrxtcmCFEuEMShGSVcVIWPohn69C2TFSfclaoscP@SwzN/W1Nh4zXWmcqgLSFeIAXJMsD)

Answer (score 5):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 50 bytes

```
([][()]){{}({}[({})]){{}<>({}())(<>)}{}([][()])}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XyM6NlpDM1azurpWo7o2GoghHBs7IFNDU1PDxk6zFsiCKgOK//9vqACCRkBoCoWG5grGAA)

Outputs nothing for 0, which in brain-flak is equivalent. If this is not acceptable, than append this for `+4` bytes: `({})`

Explanation:

```
#Push stack-height-1
([][()])

#While true:
{

    #Pop the stack-height-1 off
    {}

    #If 'a' is the element on top of the stack, and 'b' is the element underneath it, then
    #Pop 'a' off, and push (a - b)
    ({}[({})])

    #If (a-b) is not 0...
    {
        #Pop (a-b) off
        {}

        #Switch stacks
        <>

        #Increment the value on the other stack
        ({}())

        #Push a 0 back to the main stack
        (<>)

    #Endif
    }

    #Pop either (a-b) or the 0 we pushed
    {}

    #Push stack-height-1
    ([][()])

#Endwhile
}

#Toggle to the alternate stack and display the counter
<>
```

Comment: [Different approach, same length](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146421/57100)

Comment: @Riley Nicely done! :)

Comment: [Slight improvement for 48 bytes](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XyM6OjZWQ1OzWqO6VkPTBkhGA7FmrGZ1da2NHVhQU8PGTrO2uhZI2Nj9/2@oAIJGQGgKhYbmCsYA "Brain-Flak – Try It Online")

Comment: @WheatWizard I tried that also, but it loops forever on empty input. `-0+1 = 1`

Answer (score 5):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 8 bytes

**Solution:**

```
+/1_~~':
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X1vfML6uTt3KUAEEjYDQFAoNzRWM//8HAA)

**Examples:**

```
+/1_~~':1 1 1 2 2 5 5 5 5 17 3
4
+/1_~~':()
0
+/1_~~':-3 3 3 -3 0
3
```

**Explanation:**

Interpreted right-to-left:

```
+/1_~~': / the solution
     ~': / equal each-previous
    ~    / not (ie differ)
  1_     / 1 drop, remove first as this is different to null
+/       / sum up trues
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 35 bytes

*-8 bytes thanks to H.PWiz.*

Out-golfed by a [recursive version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146436/68615). Haskell is pretty much the best at recursion and I missed it. >_<

```hs
f l=sum[1|x<-zipWith(/=)l$tail l,x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hx7a4NDfasKbCRrcqsyA8syRDQ99WM0elJDEzRyFHpyL2f25iZp6CrUJuYoGvgkZBUWZeiYKeQpqmQnR0rI5CtAGY0FEwhNJgvqGOgpGOgjFQ1BzKhSAjiDhITNcYrACIQCyD2Nj/AA)

It'd be awesome if anybody figured out how to employ [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76364/68615).

### Alternate solution, 36 bytes

```hs
f l=sum[1|True<-zipWith(/=)l$tail l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hx7a4NDfasCakqDTVRrcqsyA8syRDQ99WM0elJDEzRyEn9n9uYmaegq1CbmKBr4JGQVFmXomCnkKapkJ0dKyOQrQBmNBRMITSYL6hjoKRjoIxUNQcyoUgI4g4SEzXGKwAiEAsg9jY/wA)

Comment: [Also 35](https://tio.run/##LYpNCoMwFISvMosuFJ5tootumiN4gpBFFoqhLxKqghbvHk0Uhvn5mMFO3445xh6spsVruRcrbeWn@rsAfszWMZjWl9pM9NaNUPA2tCjCz40znuhLaG0IWmQjyDvzloSa0Jz0fc9L9cUTq5p8OJWaMCYe)

Comment: That tip misses the crucial fact that you'd need to `uncurry` the function `f` to get it to work. This [`sum.map fromEnum.(zipWith(/=)=<<tail)`](https://tio.run/##LYq9DsIgFEZf5Y6Q0ErbwaVMpqNJN02Q4caIJQKSgosPL9Kf5EvuPSdnwvh6WJs1CLjl@HG1wwB6frvBFyBfEy4mTeQgqOj7hMbS7ND4kpfwDCTMxieoQVOQkisGkjNo9rtyw6Bl0BV73HFbu/nFVd0alC0fVyr/7triM@bqehrHPw "Haskell – Try It Online") is probably the closest you get, but it won't work with `[]` and is 37 bytes..

Answer (score 5):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 50 bytes

```
(([][()]){[{}]<({}[({})])>{(<{}>)()}{}([][()])}<>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0MjOjZaQzNWszq6ujbWRqO6NhqIgXy7ag2b6lo7TQ3N2upamKJaGzvN//91jRVAEEgZAAA)

```
# Get ready to push the answer
(

# Push stack height - 1
([][()])

# Loop until 0 (until the stack has a height of 1)
{

  # Pop the old stack height and subtract it 
  #(cancels the loop counter from the final answer)
  [{}]

  # Pop the top of the stack and subtract the next element from that
  # Don't include this in the final answer
  <({}[({})])>

  # If not 0
  {

    # Pop the difference between the last two numbers
    # Don't include this in the final answer
    (<{}>)

    # Add 1 to the final answer
    ()

  # End if
  }{}

  # Push stack height - 1
  ([][()])

# End while
}

# Switch to the off stack so we don't print anything extra
<>

# Push the total sum. This is the number of times the if was true
)
```

Comment: Congrats for 10k rep!

Comment: @Pavel Thanks! It took me forever to get the last few hundred. I've been too busy with other stuff :(

Comment: I had [this](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XyM6NlpDM1ZTo9qmulajujYaiIFcu2oNTQ2giJ1mbXWtDUyRXa2Nneb//4YKRgomQGgAhIYKBgA)

Comment: @H.PWiz I had that at one point, but I like how the pop cancels the stack height push.

Answer (score 5):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 65 bytes

Not as short as I'd like, but that's just Java for you.

Test by passing the array as a comma delimited list.

```java
a->{int s=0,i=1;for(;i<a.length;s+=a[i-1]!=a[i++]?1:0);return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9BT4QwEIXP5VeMeyoBGtCbFT17cC8eSQ@V7WJXKKQtazaE347TuhtNmk5e@@bNNyd5lsU4KXM6fG1tL52DN6nNkhBtvLJH2SrYLwmQoKGjeDcCZMoTsiYJmeaPXrfgvPRYzqM@wIDt9N1bbbroxCjyJ23noAbZlIK5qdee7vJdCCPXYGvlpQajviE8BDvrlen8pwim42gDAWjMKDnop38GlFkWp5GY0miBrlfcolOWTdI6hYKGDvxiSDTQNI5eA@HFeTWwcfZsQlZPDetozElvu16X3IPB3E0Wz0tAcXWZ67riAY0j0I3GZbVsdFGJu1CzTLxUj2XKrfKzNeD4uhGerNtW5fB77uN5@AE)

Comment: If the empty array wasn't a test case (and I don't find it really relevant, actually), one could have used: `a->{int s=0,p=a[0];for(int n:a)s+=p==(p=n)?0:1;return s;}` (57 bytes).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I know! I wrote that out and thought I'd managed to cut down the bytes but it failed on that first case.

Comment: 56 bytes: `a->{int s=0;for(int i:a)s+=a[0]!=(a[0]=i)?1:0;return s;}`

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ITL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98zxOf////RhjoKEGQERqZIyNBcR8E4FgA)

### How it works

```
ITL  - Full program.

I    - Increments (deltas).
 T   - Get the indices of truthy values (gets the indexes of non-0 elements).
  L  - Length.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>24</s> <s>21</s> 16 bytes

*Thanks to @MartinEnder for -3 bytes and noticing a bug*
*-1 byte thanks to @tsh*
*-4 bytes thanks to @Leo*

```
m`^(\S+)¶(?!\1$)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qEZyg8D83IU4jJlhb89A2DXvFGEMVzf//uQy4DBQMgdiAy1DBSMFYwdAcyABBIxCXS9dYAQSBFFCBqYKhKZehEQgqGIEpAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 23 <del>24</del> <del>26</del> <del>29</del> bytes

```
Length@Split@#~Max~1-1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zexItonNS@9JMMhuCAns8RBWddQxyBW7X9AUWZeSXRadLWusQ4IAimD2tjY/wA)

- -1 byte thanks to Martin Ender!
- -2 bytes thanks to JungHwan Min! nice use of `Split[]`.
- -3 bytes thanks to totallyhuman!

a little explanation:

`Split` will divide an array into a list of lists (of same elements), that is, turning `{1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1}` into `{{1}, {2, 2}, {3}, {1, 1}}` . So, `Length@Split@#` is the quantity of consecutive segements. `Max[*****-1, 0]` is used to deal with `{}` input.

Comment: [26 bytes.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P6TIwTGp2ME5J7PAwSUzLS21KDUvObXYQVntf0BRZl5JdFp0ta6xDggCKYPa2Nj/AA "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Comment: 24 bytes: `Max[Length@Split@#-1,0]&`

Comment: 23: `Length@Split@#~Max~1-1&`

Answer (score 4):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 3 bytes

```
ΔyΣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr//9yUynOL//@P1jXWUYAgEMsgFgA)

**Explanation**

```
Δ     absolute differences between consecutive elements
 y    sign: 1 if positive, -1 if negative, 0 if zero
  Σ   sum
```

Comment: Clever usage of the `sign` builtin!

Comment: @NickClifford Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

```
Ltg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/36ck/f///9G6xjogCKQMYgE)

#### Explanation

```
Ltg    Input: [1,1,1,2,2,3]
  g    Group equal elements together: [[1,1,1],[2,2],[3]]
 t     Drop the first group (if any): [[2,2],[3]]
L      Return the length of the list: 2
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 18 bytes

```perl6
{sum $_ Z!= .skip}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##fY9NTsMwFIT3PsUgIZrQOk1qfiSiAlv2rAgWCsmDRiSOVTsSVcnJ2HGxYldZVLTUs7Ct741nrGlZX22aFc6KRa7eiRdtpyzmm7XpGpy@4Olkjsh8VLr3U/eWjKOoK0UmCKMm1zdrBnhUKQeiom1egylGfHSH53KMafjzHT0om7opNxItKC@Dc56Ek@3V5lU9cTmsZ6wzhEf3fsp0nSuMt2EpY2/tcgjmtwicS3fWeehTU2GpdMeSTBHCF6kML4l0vcLufwZTuO9KWb/JEnjNnC4HJdcQEl8ALlgmcXh5HLMslscxEvkfTjyO5RG3ryVcHXkAC7bTXMi/eMYyLuDltngPi18)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{ # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  sum         # count the number of True values

      $_      # the input
    Z!=       # zip using &infix:«!=»
      .skip   # the input, but starting from the second value
              # (implicit method call on ｢$_｣
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Symbolic Python](https://github.com/FTcode/Symbolic-Python), <s>120</s> 117 bytes

Golfed 3 bytes by removing an explicit cast to integer (using unary `+`) for the counter variable - this means that if there are no changes in the array the output will be `False` instead of `0`, but this is [allowed by meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9067/60919).

```
___=-~(_==_)
__('___=~-'+`_>_`[___::___]+`__`[-~___]+'(_)')
__('__=___=_>_'+';___+=_[__]!=_[-~__];__=-~__'*___)
_=___
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##NY2xDoMwDET3fkU7OTRkoiwg90dQdIguIJVSqSws@XX3EgnpZPvsd/LvWKftvbzC99jn7WMGQENyUEV1AZzkRQriRzwxDnRdxxLpaUMqszhUcuKaE4TFS8/RK5iKN7ZMx748AOTOIzMZN7Ohqa/Uo6g91cQ/)

```
# LINE 1: Generate value '2' for utility
___=-~(_==_)

# LINE 2: Get len(input) - 1
__('___=~-'+`_>_`[___::___]+`__`[-~___]+'(_)')
   '___=~-'+`_>_`[___::___]+`__`[-~___]+'(_)'     # Generate string '___=~-len(_)'
            `_>_`[___::___]                       #    'le' spliced from 'False'
                           +`__`[-~___]           #    'n' indexed from '<function ...>'
   '___=~-'+                           +'(_)'     #    Remaining characters in plaintext
__(                                          )    # Execute this to get len(input) - 1

# LINE 3: Main calculation loop
__('__=___=_>_'+';___+=_[__]!=_[-~__];__=-~__'*___) 
__(                                               ) # Execute:
   '__=___=_>_'                                     #   Set var1, var2 to 0
               +';                           '*___  #   len(input) - 1 times do:
                       _[__]!=_[-~__]               #   Compare input[var1, var1 + 1]
                  ___+=              ;              #   Add this to var2
                                      __=-~__       #   Increment var1

# LINE 4: Set output variable ('_') to the result calculated.
_=___
```

Comment: =_= what is this wizardry?

Answer (score 4):

## Elm, 59 bytes

```
f x=case x of
 a::b::c->f(b::c)+if a/=b then 1 else 0
 _->0
```

You can test this out [here](https://elm-lang.org/try).  Paste the following code to get started:

```
import Html exposing (text)

f x=case x of
 a::b::c->f(b::c)+if a/=b then 1 else 0
 _->0

main = 
  f [0,0,1,0]
  |> Debug.toString
  |> text
```

Comment: @Steffan Thanks.  That's not the first time I've done that.  Stuck in the Haskell mindset I guess.

Comment: Well [Haskell allows it too](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwjY5sThVoUIhP41LwdAqSdcuiUsBRP7PTczMsy0oyswrUUlTiDbUMdIx1jGJ/Q8A "Haskell – Try It Online") lol

Comment: @Steffan You basically never use `case` in Haskell instead you use pattern matching which requires parenthesis due to the order of operations.

Comment: I know, but you still use pattern matching in list comprehensions, where you can omit the parens.

Comment: I was just thinking it's too bad you can't do a pattern match like `a::a::c`. Stuck in the Prolog mindset I guess. ;)

Comment: @DLosc You can also do them in Curry, which is much closer to Elm.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>52</s> 45 bytes

*(-7 bytes thanks to Julian)*

```powershell
$i=0
$args|%{$i+=$p-ne$_-and$p-ne$n
$p=$_}
$i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBBS8NAEIXP2V8xh9EmuAtpcvAgC4GCV8V6EwkxndqUmMTsBoU0vz3OupXaLrMw8977ZmG79ot6s6O6nnGrxxkrHQss@ndzuBqxutHYqYYwV0Wz8W0jsNOYTwKreRIiCwXwkVmYhZGEODqN8eUsYRm5eyZdppYSEgkp527ZSc8dX4mPsJ38s1X6i3G5LvZwBAe4b3sqyp16eNtTaWEUAVoyVgLSd8cKbUAD5iz3ZIba8nSNW8hcSAQvj@vVYGz74fHXjPlgPZQlGeO4I6Po87TvjiPPTK8KQy7jNoHat1UDCwkLZz/9PXVcwNok@D/n@Qc)

Takes input `$args`, dumps it into a for loop, each iteration checking whether the `$p`revious value is `-n`ot`e`qual to the current value `$_`, and whether the previous value is `$n`ull. Exploits the Boolean-to-int implicit converstion to accumulate that into `$i`. Outputs `$i` at the end.

The initial `$i=0` is needed to account for if the input is empty, and to (properly) account for when the input is a single value.

Comment: 5 years late :) [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##XZBBS8NAEIXP2V8xh9EmuAtpcvAgC4GCV8V6EwkxndqUmMTsBoU0vz3OupXaLrMw8977ZmG79ot6s6O6nnGrxxkrHQss@ndzuBqxutHYqYYwV0Wz8W0jsNOYTwKreRIiCwXwkVmYhZGEODqN8eUsYRm5eyZdppYSEgkp527ZSc8dX4mPsJ38s1X6i3G5LvZwBAe4b3sqyp16eNtTaWEUAVoyVgLSd8cKbUAD5iz3ZIba8nSNW8hcSAQvj@vVYGz74fHXjPlgPZQlGeO4I6Po87TvjiPPTK8KQy7jNoHat1UDCwkLZz/9PXVcwNok@D/n@Qc "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: Where's the $n come into existence? @Julian

Comment: Oh. $null. Derp.

Comment: yep, it is not very aesthetic, but I can't think of any cleaner approach

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
#IẊ≠
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/X9nz4a6uR50L/v//H61rrAOCQMogFgA)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
¥ĀO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0NIjDf7//0cb6ihAkBEYGccCAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 24 bytes

```r
cat(sum(!!diff(scan())))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKO4NFdDUTElMy1Nozg5MU9DEwj@GyoYKRgrmCiYgqHZfwA)

Same as the MATL answer, just used `sum(!!diff))` since there's no `nnz`.

Comment: +1 I thought using `rle` would be shorter, but nope, `length(rle()$v)` uses too many characters and is off by one.

Comment: @NealFultz it's probably still worth posting as an answer! Always good to see another approach. And you should use `sum(rle()$v|1)` instead of `length` anyway. :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 24 bytes

```
UpO@0I>I!^-u>q.uvv$!^;)p
```

[Try it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgIFUgcAogICAgTyBACjAgSSA%20IEkgISBeIC0gdQo%20IHEgLiB1IHYgdiAkICEKICAgIF4gOwogICAgKSBwCg==&input=LTMgMyAzIC0zIDE=&speed=5)

Note that Cubix uses 0 to indicate that there are no more inputs, so 0 cannot be in the list.

#### Explanation

Unfolded:

```
    U p
    O @
0 I > I ! ^ - u
> q . u v v $ !
    ^ ;
    ) p
```

We start at the `0`, pushing the counter (initialized with `0`) and the first input (`I`) onto the stack.

We then enter the loop.  At each iteration of the loop, we get the next input with `I`.  If it's 0, we've run out of inputs, so we rotate the counter to the top (`p`), `O`utput, and exit (`@`).

Otherwise, we take the difference of the top two elements.  If it's nonzero, we rotate the counter to the top, increment it, and rotate it back to the bottom with `p)q`.  We then pop the difference with `;` before moving to the next iteration.

All the characters not mentioned here are just control flow.  There tend to be a lot of those in Cubix programs.

Comment: @MickyT Good approach, but you seem to be overcounting by 1.  You could swap the `0` for a `(`, but that fails on the empty input.

Comment: apologies, will look at it again

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 8 bytes

```apl
+/2≠/⊃,⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wRtfaNHnQv0H3U16zzqWgQUUzDgAmIFQzAJYhsqGCkYKxiag5mGYC5QAMg7tN5YAQRBtAEA)

**How?**

`⊃,⊢` - the list, with the first value repeated for the case of single element

`2≠/` - changes list, not equal for every 2 elements

`+/` - sum

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 50 bytes

```
(([][()]){[{}({}[({})])]{{}()(<()>)}{}([][()])}<>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0MjOjZaQzNWszq6ulajujYaiIG82GogT1PDRkPTTrMWyIQqqrWx0/z/31ABBI2A0AQIjQE)

Since everyone is posting their 50 byte solutions here is mine (I have a [48 byte one](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XyM6OjZWQ1OzWqO6VkPTBkhGA7FmrGZ1da2NHVhQU8PGTrO2uhZI2Nj9/2@oAIJGQGgKhYbmCsYA) but it was a simple modification of DjMcMayhem's so I did feel it worth posting)

## Explanation

This answer extensively uses value canceling.

Un-golfed it looks like

```
([][()])({<{}({}[({})])>{<{}>()(<()>)}{}<([][()])>}<>)
```

Here we compute the delta's until the stack has one item left, each time we accumulate one value from the inner loop if the delta is non zero.

This is a pretty straight forward way of doing it.

To make this golfy we begin value canceling.  The first one and the one that should be obvious to any hardened brain-flak golfer is the stack heights.  It is a well known fact that

```
([])({<{}>...<([])>}{})
```

is the same as

```
(([]){[{}]...([])}{})
```

When the values are modified by one, the same holds.  This gives us

```
(([][()]){[{}]<({}[({})])>{<{}>()(<()>)}{}([][()])}<>)
```

You may notice this didn't even save us bytes, but don't fret it will become more useful as we go on.

We can perform another reduction,  if you see a statement

```
<(...)>{<{}> ...
```

you can actually reduce it to

```
[(...)]{{} ...
```

This works because if we enter the loop `[(...)]` and `{}` will cancel, and if we don't the value of `[(...)]` already was zero in the first place and doesn't need to be canceled.  Since we have an occurrence of this pattern in our code we can reduce it.

```
(([][()]){[{}][({}[({})])]{{}()(<()>)}{}([][()])}<>)
```

That saved us 2 bytes but it also put two negs next to each other.  These can be combined to save us another 2.

```
(([][()]){[{}({}[({})])]{{}()(<()>)}{}([][()])}<>)
```

And that's our code.

Answer (score 3):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 2 bytes

```
ėl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//8j0nP@pj9om/o/WNVYAQSBlEAsA)

This abuses a bug (or feature?) of Gaia, that run-length-encoding doesn't take the last run of elements into account. Note that I have double checked, it works for all test cases.

- `ė` - Run length encoding (with the flaw described above).
- `l` - Length.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 35 bytes

```
a=>a.filter((e,i)=>e-a[i+1]).length
```

Comment: I wonder if it could be shortened by using recursion. But my best attempt is 35 as well: `f=([a,...b])=>1/a?!!(a-b[0])+f(b):0`

Comment: @Arnauld I'd tried that too, but miscounted and thought it was 36 bytes, otherwise I'd have added it in as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
l #.+
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=l+%23.%2B&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%5D%0A%5B0%5D%0A%5B0%2C+1%5D%0A%5B0%2C+0%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+17%5D%0A%5B1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%5D%0A%5B-3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+-3%2C+0%5D&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
   .+  Deltas
  #    Filter on identity (space)
l      Get length
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 37 + 2 (`-ap`) = 39 bytes

```perl
$\+=$F[$_]!=$F[$_-1]for 1..$#F}{$\|=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lRttWxS1aJT5WEULrGsam5RcpGOrpqSi71VarxNTYGvz/b6gAgkZAaPwvv6AkMz@v@L9uYgEA)

Comment: 34 bytes, based on your answer: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tZAO70otUDFLVolPlbRFkzrGsbqGOrpqSi7/f/PZcBloGAIxAZchgpGCsYKhuZABggagbhcusYKIAikDP7lF5Rk5ucV/9dNLAAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online"). 31 bytes, using regex instead: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lZD01Zfw95GMSZYUyMmWFtTQcNeMcYwJklTP/3/fy4DLgMFQyA24DJUMFIwVjA0BzJA0AjE5dI1VgBBIGXwL7@gJDM/r/i/bgEA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## J, 10 bytes

```
[:+/2~:/\]
```

Infixes of length 2... are they unequal? `2 ~:/\ ]`

Sum the resulting list of `0`s and `1`s: `+/`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/6OttPWN6qz0Y2L/a3Ip6Smop9laqSvoKNRaKaQVc3GlJmfkA1XaKqQpGEA4hhCOgiGKHEzWGMw1VDACsgzNIWJGUDFDsDhQBllpvLECCAIpg/8A)

Comment: `[:+/0=-/\ ` ought to work for I think 9 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 4 bytes

```
ltr8
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ltr8&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C2%2C2%2C5%2C5%2C5%2C5%2C17%2C3%5D%0A%5B%5D%0A%5B0%5D%0A%5B0%2C1%5D%0A%5B0%2C0%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C17%5D%0A%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C2%2C2%2C3%5D%0A%5B-3%2C3%2C3%2C-3%2C0%5D&debug=0)

"literate"

The number of changes is equal to the number of runs, ignoring the first run if any. `r8` run length encodes the input, `t` removes the first element if any, and `l` finds the length of the resulting list.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 31 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.chunk{|x|x}.drop(1).size}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyflmf7X9cusTpRLzmjNC@7uqaipqJWL6Uov0DDUFOvOLMqtfZ/Zl5BaYmCrUI0l4JCdKyOAjpQVrC1UzAASRpgyiJJ6igYosmDJQ2hkgbYJME6DXUUjHQUjIH6zWFqwJLGUEkIMoKoAqoASxqBJHWNwfqACMQC2wDVGcvFBfRVsQLYc3q5iQUaaml5mv8B)

Comment: Instead of `.drop(1)` you can do `[1..-1]`

Comment: @Cyoce Unfortunately `drop` returns an Enumerator, not an Array, so that doesn't work.

Comment: huh. It returns an Array on my version.

Comment: @Cyoce Which version?

Comment: I'm on 1.9.3 but why can't you take the `size` of an Array anyway?

Comment: I realized I misspoke above; I meant  `chunk` returns an Enumerator, which is why you can't call `[]` on the result and have to use `drop` instead.

Answer (score 2):

## C (gcc 5.4.0), 61 bytes

```
f(c,v)int*v;{int*p=v,s=0;for(;p<v+c-1;s+=*p++!=*p);return s;}
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##jY7LCsIwEEXX@hWxIORV6MPHIvZL1EWJpnZhDGnNpvTb48QuqmBAGJIJc86dyLSR0nuFJXek1T11YgiXqRzvqkyoh8XCHByTaS46VlHD2ApOIuy1f1qNOjF6ENC9bjUOTW0byZG81RZRCg9H0LBcGAszhZP15aQTjhTOOAr48UyGkRDxg8hnIosgxQfCUf4XFcvazBRsBqeExH0E3n3BUxWTFTG2s5GW73Co0E3/Gf0L)

`f` is a function taking the length of the array and a pointer to the first element of the array, and returning the number of changes in the array;

This submission utilizes undefined behavior (`*p++!=*p`, p is used twice in an expression in which it is changed), which works on my machine (gcc 5.4.0) and on TIO, but may not work on other implementations or versions.

Explanation:

```
f(c,v)int*v;{ // old-style declaration for v, and implicit-int for c and return value
    int*p=v,s=0; // p is a pointer to the current item, s is the number of changes
    for(;p<v+c-1;s+=*p++!=*p); // for each consecutive pair of integers, if they are different, add one to the number of changes
    return s; // return the number of changes
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe add a link to an online testing environment?

Comment: @JonathanFrech Added

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
γ¦g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3OZDy9L//4821FGAICMwMkVChuY6CsaxAA)

An alternative to Erik's answer.

```
γ¦g  ~ Full program.

γ    ~ Group into runs of equal adjacent elements.
 ¦   ~ Remove the first group (if there are any).
  g  ~ Length.
```

Comment: Ah, missed that that was a case.

Answer (score 2):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/j-uby), 37 bytes

```rb
:zip%:rotate|~:[]&(0..-2)|:count++:!=
```

More "readable":

```rb
(:zip % :rotate) | (~:[] & (0..-2)) | (:count + +:!=)
```

Explanation:

```rb
:zip%:rotate                        # zip a with itself, rotated by one position. this yields [[a[0], a[1]], [a[1], a[2]], [a[2], a[3]], ...]
           |~:[]&(0..-2)            # discard the last pair, as that's [a[-1], a[0]], not one of our changes
                       |:count++:!= # count the pairs with unequal first and second elements (those are changes)
```

#### 25 bytes (conversion of @daniero's [Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146437/41042))

```rb
~:each_cons&2|:count++:!=
```

Explanation

```rb
~:each_cons&2            # for every pair [a[i],a[i+1]] in a:
            |:count++:!= # count the number of pairs with unequal first and second elements
```

Comment: Why is this non-competing?

Comment: @Pavel Language version post-dates the challenge.

Comment: @Cyoce [non-competing isn't a thing anymore](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12877/59183)

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, 17 bytes

Packages: Core Utilities, sed

```
uniq|sed 1d|wc -l
```

Takes an input array of one element per line.

### How does it work?

The input goes to stdin, one array element per line, to `uniq`. `uniq` squeezes multiple *consecutive* identical lines into one, then `sed 1d` purges the first line, passing the rest to `wc`. `wc -l` simply counts the number of lines and outputs the count.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 51 bytes

```
[range(1;length)as$i|select(.[$i]!=.[$i-1])]|length
```

Expanded

```
[                              # create an array containing
    range(1;length) as $i      # a copy of the input for
  | select(.[$i]!=.[$i-1])     # each successive element difference
] 
| length                       # length of final array
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9NCsMgEEb3PcWUZpGAFk0WhYaeJLiQxqYW0TQxdOPZazWS0p/IoDO89wlzu/tWXKDllh83ANAwBH9nBy7cZOZkRfjiCOivkjhdOFnnKU8RlAiq8MvhrSVeLTxVmcQoJV7OHFdzOlTsCKs/8nFL55uB607ktFZCd/Za8DGTbhRKnG2@bzLJtqf4YMoK5pLj/dP0Vho9eoz1pBSWup9sGAb@wGayYXgB)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 23 bytes

```julia
~a=sum([0;diff(a).!=0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/vy7Rtrg0VyPawDolMy1NI1FTT9HWIFbzf25igUadTrRCdKwOF2e0AYTUUTCEMSAihjoKRjoKxkBxcxgfgowgEmBBXWOwEiACsUAaYzUVauwUijPyy/8DAA)

- The unary operator `~` is redefined to save bytes.
- `sum` returns an error on an empty (untyped) array, so the array is padded with a `0`.

Comment: [22 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/vy7Rtrg0VyPawDolMy1NI1FTz84gVvN/bmKBRp1OtEJ0rA4XZ7QBhNRRMIQxICKGOgpGOgrGQHFzGB@CjCASYEFdY7ASIAKxQBpjNRX0auwUCooy80py8v4DAA) using `diff`

Comment: Thanks, amelies! I used your solution and changed this answer to a community wiki.

Comment: The last test case is not valid though? 3 is expected instead of 2

Comment: ouch true! Then the best I can do is [23 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/vy7Rtrg0VyPawDolMy1NI1FTT9HWIFbzf25igUadTrRCdKwOF2e0AYTUUTCEMSAihjoKRjoKxkBxcxgfgowgEmBBXWOwEiACsUAaYzUVauwUijPyy/8DAA)

or 24 if you want to use `≠`

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
ĠḢL
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLEoOG4okwiLCIiLCJbMSwgMSwgMSwgMiwgMiwgM10iXQ==)

Alternatively:

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
¯TL
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCr1RMIiwiIiwiWzEsIDEsIDEsIDIsIDIsIDNdIl0=)

`¯ꜝL` would also work.

All of these solutions can be 2 bytes by removing `L` and adding the `l` flag.

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 68 bytes

```rust
|u:Vec<_>|u.iter().fold((0,0,0),|(u,v,w),&x|(u+w*(v!=x)as i8,x,1)).0
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqLS4ZMGGtDyF3MTMPA3N6pzUEoU026WlJWm6FjddakqtwlKTbeLtakr1MktSizQ09dLyc1I0NAx0gFBTp0ajVKdMp1xTR60CyNQu19IoU7St0EwsVsi00KnQMdTU1DOAmvXMmouroCgzryQnT1FDqbpWSUchTaMsNVkxOlZT0xqHlAE-OR1DPLKGBGSNdIx1DM3xG6ADUgZUiEeVrrEOCAIpiFNrIb5dsABCAwA)

### Non-Competing [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 63 bytes

This version crashes on 0-length inputs so doesn't technically complete the challenge. I think it's more elegant though.

```rust
|u:Vec<_>|u.iter().fold((0,u[0]),|(u,v),&x|(u+(v!=x)as i8,x)).0
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqLS4ZMGGtDyF3MTMPA3N6pzUEoU026WlJWm6Fjfta0qtwlKTbeLtakr1MktSizQ09dLyc1I0NAx0SqMNYjV1ajRKdco0ddQqgAxtjTJF2wrNxGKFTAudCk1NPQOoMS-subj09QuKMvNKcvIUNZSqa5V0FNI0ylKTFaNjNTWtubBLGeCT0zHEI2tIQNZIx1jH0By_ATogZUCFeFTpGuuAIJCCOLUW4t8FCyA0AA)

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/wheatwizard/haskell-golfing-library), 7 bytes

```haskell
l<tl<gr
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ2W0km6Ec0CAUuxN1czcgvyiEoXC0sSczLTM1BSFgKLUnNKUVC6oRABXmm3M0tKSNF2L5Tk2JTk26UUQ3s343MTMPAVbhZR8LgWFgiIFFYU0hehYJLYhCkcHjWuEKmCkY2QCFAOKWoIIoCTEmgWLUkwgLAA)

### Explanation

- `gr` group the list into chunks of equal sized elements
- `tl` drop the first element
- `l` get the length

### Alternate versions

#### 8 bytes

```
cne 0<δ
```

### Reflection

I'm quite happy with this. It's hard to imagine any improvements that could be made here. However while looking for alternative versions I found a few things that might be useful to add:

- `cn id` and `cn n` should likely be added.  `cn id` counts the number of `True` values in a list and `cn n` counts the number of `False` values in a list.
- `pa eq` should likely be added.

With both of these there would be another 7 byte solution:

```
cnn<paq
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$4 \log_{256}(96) \approx\$ 3.29 bytes

(This is only for v1.1.1+, ATO is on v1.1.0)

```
z[wL
```

Or, for \$5 \log_{256}(96) \approx\$ 4.12 bytes (works on all versions)

```
zyL1-
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZLqyp9DHUhbKjQgk3RhjoKEGQERsaxEBkA)

**Explanations:**

```python
        # Implicit input                [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
z[      # Forward-differences           [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
  w     # Truthy items only             [1, 1]
   L    # Length                        2
        # Implicit output
```

```python
        # Implicit input                [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
zy      # Group by consecutive items    [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2], [3]]
  L1-   # Length - 1                    2
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 30 bytes

```
i0\  ;n$\.13$\
1+>i:0(?/:{=?^$
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiaTBcXCAgO24kXFwuMTMkXFxcbjErPmk6MCg/Lzp7PT9eJCIsImlucHV0IjoiMTExMTEyMjExIiwic3RhY2siOiIiLCJzdGFja19mb3JtYXQiOiJudW1iZXJzIiwiaW5wdXRfZm9ybWF0IjoiY2hhcnMifQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

```
ssmndZ.+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v7g4Ny8lSk/7//9oQx0FCDICI@NYAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 36 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.each_cons(2).count{|x,y|x!=y}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xOlEvNTE5Iz45P69Yw0hTLzm/NK@kuqZCp7KmQtG2srb2f4FCWnR0bCwXmDaAM3QMEUy4qKGOkY6xjqE5gg@CRiBRmJCusQ4IAimgrv8A)

Comment: Didn't know about `#each_cons`! Well played. Do you mind if I translate this into a [J-uby](http://github.com/cyoce/J-uby) answer?

Comment: @Cyoce sure, go ahead

Comment: You can find it [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146991/41042)

Comment: @Cyoce Hey, that's a nice language :) It made me think of an old project of mine. It's basically a bunch of monkey patches on the most common classes used for golfing in Ruby -- String, Array, Enumerable etc. The goal was to make all operators such a `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` etc, work on any combination of these classes, and it has a few nice convenience methods and higher order functions. I never even bothered pushing it to Github but, looking at it now, it really has a lot going on. I think in combination with J-uby it could become really powerful.

Comment: @Cyoce I pushed it to Github if you wanna look at it: https://github.com/daniero/rewb. the interesting parts are in lib/rewb. It even has unit tests to demonstrate how all the stuff works. It think it J-uby/rewb could become a nice combo :D

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 94 bytes

```cs
using System.Linq;
n=>{int?i=0,a=n.FirstOrDefault();n.ForEach(x=>{i+=x==a?0:1;a=x;});return i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY1BS8QwEIXP7a/IMcHdUt2b2XQPqyvCisIKHsRDiNM60E10Ml0qS397TcCDyMDMvJmP91xcukAwDxF9Jw7fkeGoy7@q2qP/@nfahr4Hxxh8rO7AA6HTpettjOKJQkf2KM5lEdkyOnEK@C4eLHoZmZLJ65uw1EWVkWKbLEIP1QshQ0oC2cr8rQ6QEySaJiEnIK6ew73n1ZVEpdK@x8hSKaXLYiqLT8KTZRC/kbvBu3Um1ui5WYjUN41ohRGzN805SzT1whpf7ZAiP9INtHbok6NOp0C31n3IMaMXZjTGburrS23NqCelCXggL1BPc6HLaZ6XqzlXGvUP)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 bytes

```
ä- è¦0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///ASXYXDKw4tM/j/P1rXWAEEgZRBLAA)

Comment: `ä- è` works for 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 16 bytes

```matlab
@(x)nnz(diff(x))
```

[Verify all test cases here!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzL69KIyUzLQ3I1PyfrGCrUB0dyxVtAMIKhmASxDZUMFIwVjABs0DQCMQH8nSNFUAQSBnE1lpzJafm5KSV5mmk6SRr/gcA)

Quite short, seeing that Octave is a conventional language.

#### Explanation:

```matlab
@(x)               % Anonymous function that takes x as input
    nnz(       )   % Count the number of non-zero ...
        diff(x)    % ... differences between elements
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 63 bytes

```php
foreach($_GET as$g){$c+=$g!=$l?isset($l)?1:0:0;$l=$g;}echo$c*1;
```

pass the sequence as a get query with any indexes, or [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYvLCsMgEEX3/QoLs9DWgiaLQmzwQ0opQXwEJEq0q5Bvt5E24S7O3HOZ6GJ5yOgiMp9J5TFMyGB4W53JUkyY9aDcr6MhgSULqGsP9tyDl2NKOmPwRPKOdUyA3xaxauUCqAsXZT0Z/HwRUcF2Un5cu@O0oS3l96PWNFX@za2lNRvqS/kC)

my attempt, not the shortest, but it's something

Answer (score 1):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 26 bytes

```
[2 infixes 0\[...!=+]fold]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JUpJCoAgALz7iulWBJJ6CIKgf5hEuJC0gh36vWkxzMqEe9arNTFKDn84/9iAZpSU0qKvlTs3o@LQOVISlFVi8wnYb19j4BBg7Z8zeF5ynQQykqVnBUlg9XLCwfhwEYV9vuIL)

### Explanation

```
[2 infixes 0\[...!=+]fold]
[                        ]   anonymous function; argument = arr
 2 infixes                   generate infixes of length 2
           0\[      ]fold    fold the inside function over the infixes (starting = 0)
                               when iterating, stack looks like: (acc (a0 a1))
              ...              merge (a0 a1) into the stack      (acc a0 a1)
                 !=            check for inequality              (acc a0!=a1)
                   +           add to accumulator                (acc+(a0!=a1))
```

This gives the number of unequal infixes in the array, equivalent to the given problem.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 44 Bytes

```rb
->a{a.zip(a.rotate)[0..-2].count{|x,y|x!=y}}
```

Takes the array, and zips the elements with the array rotated one place. This gives pairs of `[a[0],a[1]], [a[1],a[2]], [a[2],a[3]], ...`

Then we cut off the last element because that's `a[-1],a[0]`, which we don't need here.

Finally, we count the number of pairs with inequal first and second elements (or spaces in between items of the array which change).

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 35 bytes

```
{for(i=1;i<NF;)s+=$i!=$++i;$0=s+0}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SCPT1tA608bPzVqzWNtWJVPRVkVbO9NaxcC2WNug1vD/fwUuAy4DBQMuQwUjBWMFQ3MuAA)

This requires at least 1 character as input (the character can be a space).

A version without this restriction but with several more bytes is:

```
BEGIN{RS=" "}{s+=NR>1&&p!=$1;p=$1}END{print s+0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd0686KNhWSUGptrpY29YvyM5QTa1A0VbF0LoASNS6@rlUFxRl5pUoFGsb1P7/DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>30</s> 23 + 3 = 26 bytes

+3 bytes for `-r` flag. Output is in unary.

```
s/(\S+)( \1)*//g
y/ /;/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/WF8jJlhbU0MhxlBTS18/natSX0HfWv//fy4DLgMFQyA24DJUMFIwVjA0BzJA0AjE5dI1VgBBIGXwL7@gJDM/r/i/bhEA)

Technically I could drop the second line and say each space is a unary digit for -7 bytes, but I don't want to push it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 4 bytes

```
$0-l
```

[Try it here!](https://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%240-l&input=%5B1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%5D&warnings=1&hex=0)

```
$    -   delta(input)
 0-  -  ^.remove(0)
   l - len(^)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 56 bytes

```
(loop as(x y)on(coerce(read)'list)while y count(/= x y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrBCoAgDADQXxl0aDtFdu5jZA0SxIka5dcv5V0fx1CzYS4hNcOomsFX/KCTJmSVwoJF/EXriI3eO0SBDqxParidMCcZ2YI7TG446Ac)

Answer (score 1):

### **[Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 31 bytes**

```
f=lambda y:sum(y[1:]-y[:-1]!=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XUy9CoMwGNx9iusgJvClGO1QAvZFxOErRSo0McQ45OlT3dpww/1yPsX36vqc5@HD9vliJLPtVqRRm0ml0Sg9XYZW5sX6NUS43foE3uB8Na8BjMUd@sohcBLjJOnHtYUlXQbFQlNHPd3K8ER3Vv@F6unEQceNqQAfFhdFUyt936AeqPcGNQQTZsFSyvwF)

Comment: Since this seems to only work on numpy arrays I think you are going to need to pay the bytes to `import numpy`.  (or you should at least add a disclaimer)

Comment: @WheatWizard Does that still apply when the question specifically says "an array of integers"?

Comment: To be honest I'm really not going off of a hard rule in this case, just kind of my opinion, if you would like a hard rule you should ask about it on the meta.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>48</s> 47 bytes

```php
<?foreach($_GET[a]as$a)$n+=$_GET[b]!=$a;echo$n;
```

Run with arrays `a` and `b` as GET parameters.

empty output for `0`.

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 21 bytes

Port of [my Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/146493/11261).

```
:chunk+I|~:drop&1|:+@
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWW62SM0rzsrU9a-qsUoryC9QMa6y0HSByN19l5hWUlijYKkRzKShEx-oooANlBVs7BQOQpAGmLJKkjoIhmjxY0hAqia4ZodNQR8FIR8EYqN8cpgYsaQyVhCAjiCqgCrCkEUhS1xisD4hALLANUJ2xXFxAXxUrgD2nl5tYoKHmpgnx8YIFEBoA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ä¦
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=5KY&input=WzEsIDEsIDIsIDNd)

I'm not sure if this uses features introduced after the other Japt answer, but this is much shorter

```
ä    # Map each adjacent pair through:
 ¦   #  1 if they are different, 0 otherwise

-x   # Sum the new array and print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 29 bytes

```factor
[ 2 clump [ std 0 > ] count ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc@xCsIwEAbgPU/x@wCWpBkEBVdxcRGn0iHEqEXbxuQ6SOmzx7S0heqFcOS@/4bclKbahcv5eDpscXd1Y4vqjlLRI/GkqPBUaD@84c27MZU2HtYZoo91RUXYMdYyxGrRYVmrePlo/EeXJhbam5iN/9m0J5BCQmymQG9yNjF4n@hGS0dbS/QnNj6bZB0LWYzrV1NaZPB0jbxHDl038Z95KJWNU6WfSfgC)

Counts the number of adjacent pairs whose standard deviation is greater than zero.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 51 bytes

This works for any collection whose element type defines the operator `!=`, not just arrays of integers.

```swift
{zip($0,$0.dropFirst()).filter{$0.0 != $0.1}.count}
```

The spaces around the `!=` operator are necessary; it parses `$0.0!=$0.1` as `$0.0! = $0.1`.

This can be assigned to a variable or called inline:

```swift
print({zip($0,$0.dropFirst()).filter{$0.0 != $0.1}.count}([0, 1, 2]))

let x: ([Int]) -> Int = {zip($0,$0.dropFirst()).filter{$0.0 != $0.1}.count}
print(x([0, 1, 2]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f@/LLFIocJKQSPaM68kVlNB104ByFCwVaiuyizQUDHQUTHQSynKL3DLLCou0dDU1EvLzClJLaoGChsoKNoqAGnDWr3k/NK8klouroKizLwSjQqN6FhNTQTHAJWno2CILoCqwlBHwUhHwRiozhxdHIKMIApQJHWNwVqACMQCGfj/PwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
¯ꜝL
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiwq/qnJ1MIiwiIiwiWzBdXG5bMCwgMF1cblswLCAxXVxuWzEsIDIsIDMsIDE3XVxuWzEsIDEsIDEsIDIsIDIsIDNdXG5bLTMsIDMsIDMsIC0zLCAwXSJd)

```
¯ꜝL
¯   # delta (consecutive diff)
 ꜝ  # non-zero
  L # length
```

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252885/78850 already has this answer as a note at the end

Comment: @lyxal dammit crap, do I delete then :((

Comment: [Duplicate answers are allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/46076)

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 27 bytes

```
f(l)=sgn(l[2...]-l)^2.total
```

TIL `sgn` exists. I've been using `sign` the entire time... -_-

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xobxguvauk)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ss6pkgou07)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 10 bytes

```lisp
_MS_!=BMPg
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhar4n2D4xVtnXwD0iECUPG10brGOiAIpAxioYIA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
_MS_!=BMPg
         g  ; List of command-line arguments
       MP   ; Map this function to each pair of consecutive elements:
   _!=B     ;   1 if elements are not equal, 0 if equal
 MS         ; Map this function over that list and sum the results:
_           ;   Identity function
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ṣɓ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UrBS7IKlpSVpuhZLH-5cdHLykuKk5GKoyIKbStGGOgoQZARGpkjI0FxHwTgWohQA)

##### Explanation

```python
Ṣɓ  # Implicit input
Ṣ   # Forward-differences
 ɓ  # Boolify
    # Sum the list
    # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 10 bytes

```
+´1⊸↓≠¯1⊸↓
```

Anonymous tacit function. [Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgK8K0MeKKuOKGk+KJoMKvMeKKuOKGkwoKRiAx4oC/MeKAvzHigL8y4oC/MuKAvzPigL8x4oC/MuKAvzIK)

#### Explanation

```
+´1⊸↓≠¯1⊸↓
  1⊸↓       Drop the first element from the argument list
      ¯1⊸↓  Drop the last element from the argument list
     ≠      Compare those two lists element-wise: 1 if not equal, 0 if equal
+´          Sum the resulting list of 0s and 1s
```